# Adding options [keepaspectratio=true, scale = 0.75] to \includegraphics{} in Sweave

Tags: r, sweave

I have the following R code

```
<<Q1b1, fig=TRUE>>=  
qqnorm(resid(model1), main=NULL)
@
```

and I would like to add the option [keepaspectratio=true, scale = 0.75] to the \includegraphics{} call so that the above R code chunk generates

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true, scale = 0.75]{filename.pdf}
\label{fig:1}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

I know you can specify the width and height using \SweaveOpt{width=x, height=y} but I want to specify the scale and have it keep the aspect ratio of the figure when it's generated.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can set the width for every figure in your Sweave document with `\setkeys{Gin}` instruction. For example, the following in the preamble of your document makes every figure width 80% of the text width on your page :

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.8\textwidth}
```

Otherwise you can add the `include=FALSE` argument to your code chunk and then create the `\includegraphics` instruction manually. By default, if your Sweave file is called `test.Rnw`, then the name of the pdf file generated by the code chunk will be `test-Q1b1.pdf`. So you can do something like :

```
<<Q1b1,fig=true,include=false,echo=false>>=  
qqnorm(rnorm(100))
@

\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true,scale=0.1]{test-Q1b1.pdf}
\label{fig:1}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

However, I've made some tests on your example but the `scale` parameter doesn't seem to have any effect on the figure here. Others like `angle` do, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have `\usepackage{Sweave}` in your Sweave file preamble, it will be inserted automatically as the last line before the `\begin{document}` statement.  Therefore you need to put

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.8\textwidth}
```

, which is actually the default of Sweave style file as specified in `\usepackage{Sweave}`.

**AFTER** the `\begin{document}` statement.   See Sweave document (http://www.statistik.lmu.de/~leisch/Sweave/Sweave-manual.pdf) section 4.1.2 for detail.