# Is there a way to define all Sweave options in code?

Tags: r, sweave

Quoting from the pgfSweave manual:

> How do I set subdirectories for gures and caches?
>   This is straight out of the Sweave and cacheSweave manuals (nothing new here). For a figures subdirectory use the prefix.string option:

```
\SweaveOpts{prefix.string=figs/fig}
```

> For a caching subdirectory use a code chunk at the beginning or your document like:

```
<<setup,echo=F>>=
setCacheDir("cache")
@
```

I find it annoying that the two options are in different places, R code vs. latex directive.  Is there a way to set the `prefix.string` option with R code, perhaps before `Sweave` is called?

Comment: I would like to know the answer.  I would like to know even more if there is a way to adjust both the size at which the graphic is rendered (R) and the size at which it appears in the document (LaTeX).  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11754/how-to-get-correct-dimensions-for-a-ggplot2-plot-in-beamer ...

Comment: Hmm both my questions. I don't remember what I did for that project either.

Comment: I think that part (or all?) of the difficulty is that `\SweaveOpts` is not actually a LaTeX directive. Instead, it's an instruction to Sweave. Sweave uses `prefix.string` both to tell R's `pdf()` and/or `ps()` where to put the graphics files, and to tell LaTeX where to look for them (via it's construction of `\includegraphics{}` commands).  If it were just a LaTeX directive, you'd have a better chance of a workaround via something like a `<<results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=` chunk.

Comment: @Ben Bolker: Here's [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5258901/210673) similar to the one you linked to at tex.stackexchange.  The short answer is that you either have to modify the Sweave driver or write a LaTeX function.  I'll have an expanded answer soon posted at least one of these questions.

Comment: @BenBolker: I've since learned that using `\setkeys{Gin}` is more powerful than I thought and is an easy way to change the size it appears in the document; you apparently already knew this given your answer to [the tex.se question you linked to](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11754/how-to-get-correct-dimensions-for-a-ggplot2-plot-in-beamer/11757#11757).  So I don't quite understand what you mean there when you talk about wrapping it in a macro and what the purpose of that is.

Comment: The problem is that the size at which R generates it is (IIRC) controlled separately, via `SweaveOpts` -- so I had trouble finding a way in my Sweave file to simultaneously change the dimensions of the figure that R produced and change the dimensions LaTeX used when including it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sweave options can be set globally either by using `\SweaveOpts` or in the call to `Sweave`, like this:

```
Sweave("tmp.Rnw", prefix.string="figs/figs")
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Very good to know.  FWIW, it looks like any options set via `\SweaveOpts` in `.Rnw` document have precedence over the same options set in the call to `Sweave()`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien That order makes sense.   While poking around I also found that there might be an environment variable that can help as well.  Anyone know about that?

Comment: One caveat that I just came across is the pgfSweave does not accept the prefix.string option in the driver.

Comment: @AndrewRedd: It looks like options can be passed via the `SWEAVE_OPTIONS` environment variable, and must be in the form of a single character string, with commas separating the options. Here's a valid example: `SWEAVE_OPTIONS="prefix.string=sweaveFigures/, png=TRUE"`. As usual, you can set it interactively with a call to `Sys.setenv()` or, e.g., in `etc/Renviron.site`.